# Sort Icon for UIToolbar

Tags: objective-c, icons, uitoolbaritem

Does anyone know of a good icon that would indicate to a User that a UITableView can be sorted? I'm looking for an icon to put in a UIToolbar, aside from putting a button with "Sort" for the title. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The edit button (UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit) is a widely accepted item to indicate that you can edit a table view.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UISegmentedControl in a UIToolbar or UINavigtionBar for sorting like Apple does on the Recents screen of the Phone application.